# Sharing env consts between ymls in GitHub actions

Tags: github, yaml, action

we've a bunch of actions in our GitHub repo, some env var consts like:

```yaml
env:
    FOO: ${{ secrets.FOO_SECRET }}
    PLAIN_STRING: ${{ format('{0}/foo/bar/baz', github.workspace) }}
```

The issue is that these consts are duplicated in several yml, what's the best practice of sharing these consts, I figured there's some way to include a yml, but couldn't find any in the docs, can anyone please provide any pointers?